# I can’t get a line to break in a table

Tags: html, css-tables

I've been trying to get a line break in this HTML code, but no matter what I do it will not break.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Accusative</th>
            <td>
                <p>
                    do nothing for inanimate, genitive rule for animate 
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Accusative | do nothing for inanimate, genitive rule for animate |

This is what I get when I run the code above. But this looks ugly in context, so I want it to have brakes in it.

This is what I mean when I say brakes.

do nothing for inanimate, 
genitive rule 
for animate

---

I've tried putting 
 where I want the lines to brake, but nothing changes.
I've also tried putting each into different paragraph tags. But the padding makes it too spaced out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HTML `<br />` element(s) on the place(s) where you want line breaks.

for example:

`Textte<br />xttext`
will result in:

Textte
xttext

Note: you may also use `<br>` instead of `<br />`.

Applied to your code:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Accusative</th>
            <td>
                <p>
                    do nothing for inanimate,<br />
                    genitive rule for animate 
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It doesn't matter if you put a new-line after `<br />` or not.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

Comment: Note that the [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-br-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification